# UNIX unreliable signals

Tags: c, unix, gcc, signals

In APUE(Advanced programming in the UNIX environment), in second paragraph of section 10.4, mentioned the following

*One problem with these early versions was that the action for a signal was reset to
its default each time the signal occurred*

I write the following code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void sh(int signo) {
        printf ("signo=%d\n\n", signo);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
        signal(SIGUSR1, sh);

        while (1)
                pause();
        return 0;
}
```

But I see that everytime I send SIGUSR1 (or SIGTERM) signal to the process, signal handler does not changed.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: the book is > 20y old.  Many Linux programmers are younger that it, Do not learn from  such old sources

Comment: Re “*One problem with these early versions*… I am using Ubuntu 22.04”: Ubuntu 22.04 is not an early version. What is your question? There is no actual question in your post.

Comment: The semantics of `signal` is different. On BSD-like systems it behaves one way, on System V-like system it behaves another. Always use `sigaction` for consistent behavior. IIRC this is exactly what the book should tell you to do (long time since I read it).

Comment: It will if you use `sigaction()` with SA_RESETHAND flag.

Comment: And you [can't safely call `printf()` from within a signal handler](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188): "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  [POSIX has the concept of "async-signal-safe" functions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04), which **can** be safely called from a signal handler.  `printf()` is not one of those functions.

Comment: I know that now we should use sigaction, but my question is:  "Does action for a '**signal** system call' was reset to its **default** each time the signal occurred?"

Comment: @tahzibi, that question has already been addressed in these comments: it depends.

Comment: @tahzibi, in any case, if it is your intention to clarify the question, then please do so by *editing* it.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: @0___________ Don't you be doing APUE and W. Richard Stevens dirty like that. The book's the Bible of unix programming.

Comment: The third edition of APUE is from 2013 — 
W Richard Stevens, Stephen A Rago
[Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 3rd Edn](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0321637739).

Comment: You're not using one of those "early versions".  You're using a recent version.  The behaviour described was what happened on 7th Edition Unix, and System V Unix.